# Why does this genorater code not work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple genorator code for a flight simulator. It should genorate four numbers between 0 and 7, and then update the text of a Div.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SG 0.0.0</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="squawk">0000</div>
    <button onclick="genSquawk" id="gen">Genorate Squawk</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const div = document.getElementById('squawk')

var num1 = Math.random() * 7;
var num2 = Math.random() * 7;
var num3 = Math.random() * 7;
var num4 = Math.random() * 7;

function genSquawk() {
    div.textContent = num1,num2,num3,num4;
}
```

Comment: The [assignment (`=`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) only uses **one** expression on the right side for the value. Are you wanting to combine the values somehow? If so, how so (e.g. addition, concatenation, etc.)?

Comment: could you please add expected output as well so that its easy to understand for me and others as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few changes to be made. One is the following line:

```
<button onclick="genSquawk" id="gen">Genorate Squawk</button>
```

You are referencing the `genSquawk` function on the `onclick` property, not calling it. The correct is:

```
<button onclick="genSquawk()" id="gen">Genorate Squawk</button>
```

Now it should trigger the function properly. The second one is: the syntax `num1,num2,num3,num4` is not correct, and will cause the code to display only the first num. In order to do so, use string literals: `${num1}, ${num2}, ${num3}, ${num4}`.

Finally, I do not know if you want integers or if each of the four numbers could be floats. But I added a function to generate a int number between 0 and 7.

```js
function getRandomArbitrary() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}

function genSquawk() {

  const div = document.getElementById('squawk')
  var num1 = getRandomArbitrary();
  var num2 = getRandomArbitrary();
  var num3 = getRandomArbitrary();
  var num4 = getRandomArbitrary();
  div.textContent = `${num1}${num2}${num3}${num4}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>SG 0.0.0</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="squawk">0000</div>
  <button onclick="genSquawk()" id="gen">Genorate Squawk</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`div.textContent = num1,num2,num3,num4;` is not valid syntax. If you want an an array, for instance, you could use `[num1, num2, num3, num4]`. Since you're updating the node's text content, you likely want to make these numbers a string value to insert into your `div` element. In that case, there are many ways to make a string from your series of numbers. One way is [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), something like

```
div.textContent = `${num1}, ${num2}, ${num3}, ${num4}`;
```